# Combine Two Queries in Oracle and get the data in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two queries which results below data from each table

**Query 1**

[image]

**Query 2**

[image]

I need to combine these Queries and get the data as below as we see Account ID (100) do exist the same from both queries take row for that Account ID from first Query.

[image]

Any help is much appriciated.

Comment: Please check The UNION [ALL], INTERSECT, MINUS Operators. You probably need simple UNION.

Comment: Yes I have tried with union but the issue is we need to group by by account id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both SQL Server and Oracle you can use this sort of construction....

```
Select Address_ID, Display_Value, Account_ID
from FirstTable
union
Select Address_ID, Display_Value, Account_ID
from SecondTable
Where SecondTable.Account_ID not in (select FirstTable.Account_ID from FirstTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, full outer join might help.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  t1 (address_id, display_value, account_id) as
  4    (select 1000, '10001 - Test 1', 100 from dual union all
  5     select 1000, '10002 - Test 2', 200 from dual union all
  6     select 1000, '10003 - Test 3', 300 from dual
  7    ),
  8  t2 (address_id, display_value, account_id) as
  9    (select 2000, '10001 - Test 1', 100 from dual union all
 10     select 3000, '10004 - Test 4', 400 from dual
 11    )
 12  --
 13  select nvl(a.address_id, b.address_id) address_id,
 14         nvl(a.display_value, b.display_value) display_value,
 15         nvl(a.account_id, b.account_id) account_id
 16  from t1 a full outer join t2 b on a.account_id = b.account_id;

ADDRESS_ID DISPLAY_VALUE  ACCOUNT_ID
---------- -------------- ----------
      1000 10001 - Test 1        100
      1000 10002 - Test 2        200
      1000 10003 - Test 3        300
      3000 10004 - Test 4        400

SQL>
```